# Node/Mongo: db.collection('name').find().toArray not returning results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

db.collection('name').find().toArray not returning results to my app.  When I console.log the result, it shows that the function is working.  However, it is not returning the result to my app.

```
[recipelib.js]

obj.getOne = function(id){
var recipe = "";
const myDatabase = db.db("recipe_app_db");
var o_id = new mongo.ObjectId(id);
myDatabase.collection("recipes").findOne({'_id': o_id}, function(err, 
result){
   if (err) throw err;
   recipe = result;

   /*console.log is returning the appropriate result*/
   console.log("recipe found:", recipe);

   /*not returning recipe to my app*/
   return recipe;
});
}


[app.js]

app.get('/recipe/:id', function(req,res){
  console.log("get one recipe called");
  var recipe = recipelib.getOne(req.params.id);
  res.json(recipe);
});
```

Comment: `findOne` is an `async` function. That's why you're not getting anyting back at the moment you're calling it

Comment: I keep forgetting that.  Yes, thank you.